# Why Blender 2.49 does not show button on ubuntu like it does in windows?

Tags: python, add-on, error

I have [add-on](http://www.mediafire.com/file/tkjt4f3b3pdafjs/Blender249%255Bsketchfab%255D%255Bhtm%255D%255B2019-10-16%255D.zip/file) for Blender 2.49b, python 2.6.6 and I need it to "show the button" to a user like this:

```
result=Blender.Draw.PupMenu("Sketchfab Viewer ?%t|Yes|No")
```

But button does not show up in ubuntu, but it does in windows?

To run script press Alt+P in text windows and go in to addon folder than go in to `768dd88bd0bb49a8ad0a75ab143f685a` and select `astrea-768dd88bd0bb49a8ad0a75ab143f685a.html` and hit Import. Then you should see

[image]

Edit: 
When I add print "2" on line 43 it does not show up in console so its problem in folder "newGameLib" I doubt that it contain some windows only releted command just like `cls`.

Also one thing should be changed line 3277

```
os.system("cls")
```

to

```
##os.system("cls")
```

[image]

Comment: Unlikely that this is platform related, more likely differences in the API between different Blender versions. Your function call is not enough for us to identify the problem, please post a complete minimum working example. The [How do I ask a good question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
page from the Help Center may help you improve your question.

Comment: If this is for version 2.4x and prior  may be an idea to flag as such in question.

Comment: Why are you using a version that is 10 years old?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys because there is no newer version of it

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic What are you talking about? There is no newer version of what specifically? Whoever is going to help you will have to go and download that ancient version of Blender and test the outdated and forgotten thing you are talking about. It might be helpful to provide some explanation and context and describe the thing you are trying to do to help them decide if that is something that they might want to spend their time on.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys There is no newer version od addon, its written just for Blender2.49b. Sorry if i wasn't clear enought

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic this part is obvious. I was asking about explanation and context. What addon? What is it for? Why do you need it? I see it has something to do with Sketchfab website - do you think it still works the same today as it did 10 years ago? That seems unlikely. Seems like a waste of time. Is it not?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys It works on windows its created this year

Comment: You are looking for SketchFab viewer addon? How about this addon for 2.79 and 2.8 In link here? https://github.com/sketchfab/blender-plugin

Comment: @RitaGeraghtystandsbyMonica tnx

Comment: @RitaGeraghtystandsbyMonica consider making an answer.

Comment: Re the edit. 1 and  "BinaryReader" will print when the script is imported, or run from text editor.  To see 2 printed will need to read the sketchfab binary _ie_  use the button created by script to do whatever it does. .  BSE is prob not the place to teach python.

Comment: @batFINGER What are you suggesting to me where to ask the question

Answer (score 3):

You can find your addon for 2.79 and 2.8 in link here. 
https://github.com/sketchfab/blender-plugin

If you are unfamiliar with 2.8, you can see basic tutorials in link below. 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6

Playlists of tutorials for 2.8x on page 4 and those for 2.7x on page 5. I regard those as ***best*** for absolute beginners. 
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13UpIjJEE7Oa7x5BiMsjXGW5CGOTDF03-SocRYi4Babs/

Comment: tnx a lot but that's not what I'm looking for